# Firebase-Performance iOS-SDK: Setting isDataCollectionEnabled to false again only takes effect after reinstall

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-performance

we are currently integrating the Performance plugin into our iOS App. During this process we inspected the Firebase logs and noticed something that does not seem right to us:

As suggested in the documentation we are setting the flags `Performance.sharedInstance().isInstrumentationEnabled` and `Performance.sharedInstance().isDataCollectionEnabled` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

To simulate the user opting in/out of collecting performance data we first set these values to false, installed the app, set them to true, reran the app, set them to false and reran again.

The expected behavior would be that the sdk is only collecting data during that second run but it also did that during the third run. After further investigation we found that once you set `Performance.sharedInstance().isDataCollectionEnabled` to true the feature stays enabled even if you set it to false in a later version. Only after reinstalling the app the tracing is disabled as it should be. Below you can see the filtered XCode log output of the last run showing that it is still collecting data, even if it should not.

```
2019-05-08 13:46:17.532273+0200 stage[49670:820732] 5.20.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Recording trace: _as


2019-05-08 13:47:02.218257+0200 stage[49670:821041] 5.20.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100010] Clearcut is about to send logs. 1 upload blocks will be ran.


2019-05-08 13:47:49.893332+0200 stage[49670:822055] 5.20.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Recording trace: _st_PageViewController


2019-05-08 13:47:55.067167+0200 stage[49670:822053] 5.20.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Recording trace: _st_PageViewController


2019-05-08 13:48:02.663044+0200 stage[49670:822276] 5.20.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Recording trace: _st_PageViewController
```

So it seems that a user could not opt out anymore after opting in once but this can't be the expected behavior of the sdk, so we must be missing something. Does anyone have an idea how to make sure re-disabling data collection can be forced to take effect?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Hey are you still running into this issue? What version of the SDK are you on?

Comment: Our PO decided not to use this feature in production for now, so we are currently not looking this anymore.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue, reached out to Firebase support. Will keep you guys posted on what they respond with.